# Travel path line appeared and I can't make it disappear

Tags: creality-ender-3, print-quality, ultimaker-cura, speed

This line has started to appear on my prints. I've tried to revert the settings I've changed back to my original settings but the line is still there. The previous prints didn't have this line as far as I can remember. What could possibly cause this problem? I didn't use any supports or build plate adhesion. It is annoying because those lines also appear on the prints.

[image: Screenshot of Cura's Preview for a printed model showing the travel paths]

[image: Screenshot of Cura's Travel path settings]

Comment: I'm new to 3D printing so if I asked wrong question or you need any additional printing settings let me know.

Comment: "This line has started to appear on my prints." - This probably isn't a *line* but more likely stringing due to improper retraction settings as mentioned by 0scar in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

The line in question is a travel line, so no extrusion is deliberately done there. So, if you see that filament is being deposited, your retraction settings are incorrect.

Generally, a blob is generated at the origin (or the last point after leveling) and proper retraction and travel speed should be in place to prevent filament to leak during the travel to the first printing position.

You should check your start G-code and look for retraction and speed of travel. A larger retraction and higher feed rate for travelling may prevent the deposition of filament.

Remember that the higher the temperature of the filament, the more easy it flows out of the nozzle. If you are printing hotter, or with a different material that is more fluid at the same temperature, you run into these problems.

Comment: I've tried to do that with some random gcode from the github but the "line" was still there. In the end I've decided to unistall cura and delete data. I've saved the profiles and now there isn't any issue.